# Is this reverse string function in C poorly written ? / How to make this code better?

Tags: c, function

Here is a part of code which describes a function to reverse characters of a string
(Based on exercise 1-19 of Brian W. Kernighnan Programming in C)...
( I have googled various text reverse function, but all of them us pointers or using strrev(), but I don't have an idea what a pointer is.... nor do I want to use strrev(), hence I made a reverse string function as the author wanted it to be........ )

<strike>The function:</strike>

```
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i , n ;
    char j ;
    i = 0 ;
    while(s[i] != '0') //And not EOF
    {
        ++n;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        j = s[i] ;
        s[i] = s[n - 1] ;
        s[n - 1] = j ;
    }
}
```

However I think overwritting arrays is bad , and the whole function seems awry.

P.S : It would be great if you did check and help me with the whole code here, since it would be offtopic if I did post it here, The code's main return 0; however it still doesn't work....

[EDIT]
Ok I am seriously sorry for troubling you for a typo... I can't delete this question since it has answers with upvotes however I'm sorry....

The correct function would be :

```
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i, l;
    char temp;
    for (l = 0; s[l] != '\0'; ++l);
    l--;
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[l-1];
        s[l-1] = temp;
        --l;
    }
}
```

Full Code is here :

[Code](http://pastebin.com/zRQWkx6r)

Code Working is here :

[image]

---

***UPDATE:***

I created a correct and working solution for the word 'hello':

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "hello";
    char temp;



    // do the swapping here..

    temp = s[0];
    s[0] = s[4] ;
    s[4] = temp ;

    temp = s[1] ;
    s[1] = s[3] ;
    s[3] = temp ; 

   temp = s[2] ;
   s[2] = s[2] ;
   s[2] = temp ;
   printf("%c, %s ", temp, s);   

}
```

Comment: Questions asking to improve and critique functioning code are more suitable at [codereview.se].

Comment: Strings in C are usually nul terminated (`0` or `'\0'`), not `EOF` which is a negative integer.

Comment: @Juhana but how do I migrate to Code  Review since I have a rep of just 47

Comment: @Juhana this code is very much not functioning.

Comment: your while is an endless loop and what you are doing with n is undefined behaviour

Comment: 1)`n` is not initialize. 2)`EOF` isn't `'\0'` 3)`i < n` --> `i < n/2`, `s[n - 1]` --> `s[n - i - 1]`

Comment: Ya! I edited it as much as I could if it doesn't deserve a re-opening it atleast doesn't deserve the downvotes........Thanks everyone though!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop

```
while(s[i] != EOF)
{
    ++n;
}
```

seems wrong.

1. String end is checked via `0`, not via `EOF`.
2. You never change `i`, so that you always check `s[0]`.

Comment: So shall I make it to s[i] = '0'; ??

Comment: @ArchKudo No, you should make it `s[i] != 0`.

Comment: @ArchKudo And, as said, additionally do `n = 0;` and use `s[n] != 0`.

Comment: @cmaster Is the edited code correct now ??

Comment: @ArchKudo You are getting much closer. There is still an issue with it, but why don't you try to compile your code and see if it does what you want? That way you learn to debug your code yourself, which is essential to learning programming.

Comment: @cmaster Previously too it didn't give any debug errors even when the code ran into endless loop so it is kinda hard to know what went wrong...Thanks though

Comment: @ArchKudo Removing the `{}` AND adding a `;` was about the worst thing you could do. Just have another look at the code wit hthe knowledge that `;` separates statements. What do you think what `for (n = 0; s[n] != '\0'; ++n);` does?

Comment: My noob eyes can't see it, what is wrong??I suppose `for` loop is complete by itself so it needs no further statments so I closed it.....What is that I am doing wrong here ?? Should I add a break; statment ??

Comment: @glglgl Actually, the loop `for (n = 0; s[n] != '\0'; ++n) ;` is fine, it correctly increments `n` until it points to the terminating null byte. However, the following statement isn't.

Comment: Sorry, misread that... in my mind, I was still at the `while` loop...

Comment: @cmaster do you mean `--n;` what else I can use instead of that ?? I would need something to remove the '\0' count as you suggested..

Comment: @ArchKudo Just assume you input the string `"string"`. `n` will be 6 after the first loop. So which two characters will be swapped by the first iteration of the second loop?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where you got this piece of code, but it's actually quite broken:

1. `n` is never initialized. This is undefined behavior.
2. The while loop won't terminate at all because it compares a `char` with a value that is not in the range of a `char`.
3. The while loop can't do anything sensible since its body can't change the loop condition.
4. The for loop exchanges all characters with one single array element, which effectively rotates the string right by one char. But the program will never reach this point anyway.